# DMZ to another router for WAN IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dmz

I have 2 ISPs (One I am getting rid of -- Bell Canada).

The first provider is Bell Canada and they use PPPOE and is connected via DSL and it's a modem/router in one.

The second provider is Rogers Canada and is connected via Cable and it's a modem/router in one (Hitron CODA-4582U).

**My original setup was as follows:**

1. Bell Modem/Router combo to the wall via phone-line (DSL) configured with Gateway functions on (it has Wifi - **NOT BRIDGED**).
2. Asus RT-AC88U's WAN port to Bell Model/Router combo's LAN port.
3. Asus RT-AC88U's configured using Bell's PPPOE username and password so the WAN IP is the public IP of the Bell router which is perfect!

This allowed me to have 2 networks (one from the modem/router combo and one from the Asus router). I did this setup because I couldn't get AP mode working and still have LAN connections to the Asus (only wifi would work in AP mode for some reason.. but in routing mode I can have both).

**My new setup is as follows:**

1. Rogers Hitron Model/Router combo to the wall via cable (coaxial) configured with Gateway functions on as well.
2. Asus AC-RT88U's WAN port to Rogers Model/Router combo's LAN port (just like Bell).

**Double NAT:**

But then I ran into the infamous Double-NAT problem. I realized Rogers doesn't use PPPOE and therefore doesn't have a "username" and "password" to get a direct WAN IP like with Bell..

**Proposed Resolution:**

So I decided to log into the Rogers modem/router combo and do the following:

1. Create a DHCP-Reservation for the Asus Router on 192.168.2.10
2. Assign DMZ to 192.168.2.10

**Failure:**

However, the Asus router is still showing that it has a PRIVATE WAN of 192.168.2.10 :(

How can I get it to connect to the internet directly?! I've been trying for hours but for some reason it still shows as private.

Pics (Asus configuration for Rogers):

[image]
[image]

Configuration for Rogers Modem/Router combo:
[image]

Any ideas why the Asus router is NOT getting the public IP and is being put behind NAT?

Comment: DMZ doesn't "swap roles" between the router and the selected device/host. AFAIK, on many (if not most/all), DMZ pretty much means "port forward everything", without even isolating the selected host from others.

Comment: `only wifi would work in AP mode for some reason` If it can be switched to "AP mode", which I assume would switch off its own DHCP server and so, perhaps you should connect "LAN-to-LAN" instead of "WAN-to-LAN".

Comment: Call Rogers, ask them the put their modem in Bridged Mode and then connect a router to it via the WAN interface on the router. This will give you the external IP address on your router. I have Rogers here and this is how I do it.

Comment: https://www.rogers.com/customer/support/article/bridgemode-cgn3

Comment: @TomYan I solved it. Holy crap.. So the weird part was.. I kept it connected via WAN to WAN and wifi worked in AP mode.. but not LAN ports.. so then I changed the IP of the Asus Router to something insane and not even close to the Model/Router combo.. now all of a sudden both Wifi and LAN ports work on the ASUS in AP Mode.. :l Typically NOTHING would work.. I did not expect this.